# Receive M114 command while printing using Printrun

Tags: marlin, g-code, python, serial-connection

I'm working on a project for which I use the [Printrun](https://github.com/kliment/Printrun) package to serial communicate my G-code to my 3D printer (Creality Ender 3, Marlin firmware). The idea is that I have an external button connected to an Arduino such that whenever I press this button, the `M114` command should be sent and I want to receive the nozzle Z-position.

At the moment the code looks like this:

```
from printrun.printcore import printcore
from printrun import gcoder

# some code for button
import serial
import time

arduino = serial.Serial(port = 'COM5', baudrate = 9600, timeout = 0.1)
def Button():
    data = arduino.readline()
    time.sleep(0.05)
    return data


printer = printcore('COM4',115200)

gcode=[i.strip() for i in open('MyCode.gcode')]
gcode = gcoder.LightGCode(gcode)   
printer.startprint(gcode)

button = Button()
if button == b'1':
    printer.pause()
    print(printer.send_now("M114"))
    printer.resume()
```

The code is running but I don't get any information about the outcome of the `M114` command when I press the button.

**Questions:**

1. Is there something in my code that I'm missing? How can I receive the answer from the `M114` command using Printrun?
2. Do you know any other package that allows me to receive the answer from the 3D printer?